# How to flatten an aggregate result

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

MongoDB: 3.6+

I have this Pymongo/MongoDB query:

```sql
    _data = db['history'].aggregate([
        {'$lookup': 
            {
                'from': 'mgmt_item',
                'localField': 'id_mgmt_item',
                'foreignField' : 'old_id',
                'as': 'mgmt_item'
            }
        },
        {'$match': query},
        {'$project': projection}
    ])
```

And I'm getting the following result, that is correct.

```
{ 
   "_id":"a4f2a993-749d-4b27-a9bd-c5950babd1bf",
   "id_mgmt_item":3,
   "value":99.660095,
   "image_path":"https://url/a4f2a993-749d-4b27-a9bd-c5950babd1bf.jpg",
   "mgmt_item":[ 
      { 
         "lang":{ 
            "pt_BR":"Descrição..."
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

But, I would like to *flatten* the result to have the value of **mgmt_item.lang.pt_BR** as the value for the **mgmt_item** attr, like below:

```
{ 
   "_id":"a4f2a993-749d-4b27-a9bd-c5950babd1bf",
   "id_mgmt_item":3,
   "value":99.660095,
   "image_path":"https://url/a4f2a993-749d-4b27-a9bd-c5950babd1bf.jpg",
   "mgmt_item":"Descrição..."
}
```

What change should I do in the query to get the desired result ?

Comment: Can you add your input docs to the question?

Comment: Use `$addFields` stage. `{ $addFields: { mgmt_item: { $arrayElemAt: ["$mgmt_item.lang.pt_BR", 0] }}}`

Comment: @Ashh it works like a charm. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the following $replaceRoot stage to the end of your aggregation list to flatten as you wanted:

```
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $mergeObjects: [
          "$$ROOT",
          {
            "mgmt_item": {
              $arrayElemAt: [
                "$mgmt_item.lang.pt_BR",
                0
              ]
            }
          },
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

Playground:

https://mongoplayground.net/p/iR8Qoc3TkXU

Docs:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/